# EmberJS clean store when transition on different route

Tags: ember.js

I want to clear all data from store when a user will transition 
on a different route.

I want to make this clear when the transition is done on any route but
not a sub-route (I have nested-routes).

So, in event `willTransition` I need somehow to check if the transition
route is a sub route of the parent route. In this case, I want to keep
all data from the store, otherwise I should call `this.store.unloadAll('my-object');`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can get the current route name like

```
this.controllerFor('application').get('currentRouteName');
```

This return something like `photos.photo`. So just look if there is a `.` in the string and you will know its a sub route. You can also check the parent if you need that too.

Comment: Ok, this partially works. I want to clear store data even if I leave a sub-route of that parent route where I apply willTransition event, but the willTransition from parent does not get called.. I need to handle this, by placing willTransition, in every sub-route?

Comment: Well you can probably write a mixin or base route and make ur routes use the mixin or extend from the base route.

Answer (score 1):

You already accepted an answer but I don't think it is the correct solution (seems pretty hacky and you're having problems with it already). What you actually want to do is use the `deactivate` hook of your route. Please see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_deactivate). The point of this hook is to execute code on change from the route. When subroutes change, the parent route is not deactivated.

```
deactivate: function(){
    this.store.unloadAll('my-object');
}
```

If the object you are unloading is the same across all routes, make the `deactivate` hook a mixin and make all of your parent routes extend the mixin. If its a different object per route, manually write the deactivate hook for each parent route

From you comment, there is a clear async issue you have run into. You could technically do the same thing in the `beforeModel` hook of all of your parentRoutes. It would have the same effect, which it looks like is cache invalidation and a refetch. They're may be a more Ember Data way to do this but I wouldn't know since I don't use it.

Comment: I already tried this solution, but if I had some problems with this. I posted an issue on github about this problem some days ago. Please take a look here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10996